# Show Sub-Catalog in Parent Catalog page Business Catalyst

Tags: adobe, business-catalyst

I want to show sub catalog in parent catalog page instead of products, when click parent catalog then open sub catalog and when click sub catalog then open sub catalog products, how can i do this ? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Did you a have a look here at all ? http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/user-manual/e-Commerce/Catalogs/creating-catalogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on the answer provided by thenexus00, you need to have the following conditions met:

> 1. A **parent catalogue** set up in the BC Admin (*eCommerce > Catalogs > Add Catalog*)
> 2. At least one **sub catalogue** set up (as above) and nested under your parent catalogue
> 3. At least one **product** set up (*eCommerce > Products > Add Product*) and added to your sub-catalogue

Then in your overall shop layout (*Site Manager > Module Templates > Online Shop Layouts > Overall Layout* **or** if you're using FTP, */Layouts/OnlineShop/page_content.html*) you will need to include `{tag_cataloguelist}` and `{tag_productlist}`.

Check out the BC Docs on [Online Shop Overall Layout](https://docs.worldsecuresystems.com/reference/layouts-and-tags/e-commerce/online-shop-overall-layout.html) for details on implementation of the aforementioned tags.

If the above 3 conditions are met and your online shop layouts are in their default state, as thenexus00 says, you should have your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is very straight forward. Unless the overal eCommerce layout has been changed there should be a tag for the catalogues in place and a tag for the products.

Then it is a simple manner of management:
Shop Catalogue
- Catalogue
- Catalogue

Do not add any products to the "Shop Catalogue" and only the child catalogues will show up. Then put the products in the child catalogues.